# How to quit emacs, C x, C c says "Thou shall not quit!"

Tags: emacs, elisp

New user to emacs.
Loaded a config file that contains the code below.
Now everytime I want to quit emacs, it says "Thou shall not quit!"

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-x C-c") (bind (message "Thou shall not quit!")))
(after 'evil
  (defadvice evil-quit (around dotemacs activate)
    (message "Thou shall not quit!"))
  (defadvice evil-quit-all (around dotemacs activate)
    (message "Thou shall not quit!")))
```

Here is the link to the config file.
[enter link description here](https://github.com/bling/dotemacs/blob/master/config/init-bindings.el)

Comment: Looking over the files, it seems like you could hit `Q` in Evil normal mode until it exits. You could also just remove those lines.

Comment: Try `M-x save-buffers-kill-terminal` (`M-x` is usually Alt-x or Cmd-x on a Mac)

Comment: @resueman thank you. That did it I think.

Comment: If it hurts, don't do that!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in general, you have a standard Emacs binding which has been clobbered, and you don't know how to do the thing it used to do?

To find out the default binding, you can start up a second Emacs instance without your init file, by running `emacs -Q` and then check that binding with <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>k</kbd><kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd>

That will tell you:

> C-x C-c runs the command save-buffers-kill-terminal

With that knowledge, you can return to your original Emacs instance and either do this to run that command manually:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `save-buffers-kill-terminal` <kbd>RET</kbd>

or restore the global binding:

- <kbd>M-x</kbd> `global-set-key` <kbd>RET</kbd> <kbd>C-x</kbd><kbd>C-c</kbd> `save-buffers-kill-terminal` <kbd>RET</kbd>